# Photo recognition with webcam

Tags: webcam, detection

in a few months I've got a game to play, but I want to cheat a bit :P by using some webcams.

The game is simple you drive with your car around and try to spot images that are taken of the roadside. But I was thinking if I use some webcams, I could scan the surrounding for these photos. I will probably still need to look for these photos but it helps me a lot.

I was thinking maybe I should use OpenCV with Feature Detection, but is this the smartest?

Comment: Did you have a particular programming language/framework in mind? This question is incredibly open-ended.

Comment: Im keeping it open ended for a purpose because if someone got a script in a specific language, i hope to work with that, but im guessing something like C or C++ is the best for this kinds of projects

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better than the smartest, you should look for the stronger one.

Some times ago I've worked with opencv + [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform) which gives support for rototraslation of what you're looking for and can do progressive finding by adding feature to the checks.

It may be a good idea, and you can find opencv implementation [here](http://web.engr.oregonstate.edu/~hess/index.html)